# CJAX Installation with Codeigniter- Error

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am trying to use CJAX with Codeigniter. The help documents are really confusing and I could not get them to work.
I have downloaded the CJAX and extracted it to my base root folder, with application and htaccess files.

When I try to do in a view

> /ajax.php?sample/test

I get the following error:

```
Severity: 8192
```

> Message: Non-static method plugin::initiatePlugins() should not be
>   called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context
>
> Filename: classes/core.class.php

Can somebody please guide me through an installation? 
I tried to change function initiatePlugins() to public function initiagePlugins in core.class.php but to no avail.
My htaccess file is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule  ^/?ajax/(.*)$  ajax.php?$1 [NC,QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I can really use some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking code, seems like there is method and property with same name.
In [github source](https://github.com/ajaxboy/cjax/blob/master/cjax/core/classes/plugin.class.php) 
can be found

```
public static $initiatePlugins = array();//line 66
```

and also method called

```
function initiatePlugins(){/**/}//line 524
```

I would say something is mixed up with these two variables. Can't tell more than you should see with author on github or on his page.

Answer (score 0):

To the response from **Tpojka**,  that is not the issue, as they are named the same, *but note quite*.  This scenario will not even begin to be a problem. The static variable will always 100% of the time have a **$** dollar sign in-front of it, while the function/method, will never have it, there for this is entirely not the case at all.

Also, let me say that this issue has nothing to do with mod-rewrite or htaccess either.

**Solution**

Now,  here is the solution to this problem:

One of the requirements for Cjax to work, is to have PHP setting  'Strict Standards' turned off.  That is not the case on your installation it appears this setting is on. There for you are getting this strict standard error.  I recommend to get Cjax 5.9, which is already 'Strict Standards' compliant. This should resolve the issue.